# Creating null reference

Tags: java

```
class A{

A(int i){
}
}

A obj=new A(1);
```

while creating Object if i pass positive numbers object must be created.
A obj=new A(-1);
If negetive numbers are passed it object must not be created.

How to adjsut the constructor to do this

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want an object to be created, don't call `new`. Calling `new` *always* creates an object, even if it then gets thrown away due to an exception. If you just want to avoid the caller from *receiving* an object as a result of the constructor call, you could make your constructor throw an exception. If you want them just to receive a null reference, you can't do that in a constructor.

However, you could have a static method instead, which then *conditionally* calls `new` or returns null:

```
public class A
{
    public static A createIfNonNegative(int i)
    {
        return i < 0 ? null : new A();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [**Null Object**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern.
In that case object will be created but with logic null state.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Jon Skeet (obviously) excellent answer, you can also throw an exception from constructor :

```
class A{

    A(int i){
        if(i<0) {
            throw new NumberBelowZeroException(i); // implementation of this exception is left as an exercise
        }
    }
}

A obj=new A(1);
```

This way, the object will be constructed (as constructor, by having been called, ensures object exists), but it will indicate clearly that it is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches:

1. The logic depending of the value of `i` encapsulated in the same level. In this case condition checking is needed, even if it returns null:

   ```
   A a = createAInstance(i);
   if(a == null) { // do something }
   else { // do something else }
   ```

   so depending on the algorithm you can check the condition at the level where you use `A a`:

   ```
   if(i >= 0) { A a = new A(i); // do something }
   else { // do something else }
   ```
2. The logic is implemented in A only: use Null Object to implement a null stub for A, and the code dealing with A instance shouldn't feel the difference;
3. the logic is mixed: use Null Object as in 2.